# Autocomplete not working with Node.js in webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Just downloaded WebStorm and giving Node.js a try.

Unfortunately the autocomplete does not seem to work.

I have set the node js interpreter to node.exe but saw a post saying that I should set it to the Node.js file. When I used Node.exe, at least the version was populated in the Node.js configuration dialog, however when I download the code and select the Node.js file I get "Version not found".

Either way, autocomplete does not work.

Comment: Which versions of WebStorm and Node.js do you use?

Comment: Do you have the source JS files configured for Node.js modules? See [this screenshot](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/5298/20121028192235.png).

Comment: @WernerVesterås  : webstorm 5.0.3 and Node.js  v0.8.14

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Thanks for the screenshot. I have exactly the same screen configuration apart from the version number. I have downloaded the source as well but still not working, but as I said above when I selected node.js as the interpreter I did not get version number populated.

Comment: Try 5.0.2 version (replace numbers in the download link) and report if it works better. 5.0.3 has known issues with NodeJS.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Thanks for all your help. Woke up this morning and did two things. Went to managed scopes and added fs module to specific folder (even though all the modules were added to the parent project folder) and then saw "invalidate caches" option. Lo and behold all seems to be working, not sure which one resolved it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing a "File -> Invalidate cache" all appeared to work.

Comment: Darn. You just saved my day dude. One word. `Invalidate`

Answer (score -1):

Delete **.idea** (hidden) directory from your project folder and open the project again.

`"File->Invalidate cache"` did not work for me.